# Simulate Flip-Flop D ISim 12.3

Tags: simulation, vhdl, fpga, flip-flop

How can I simulate this vhdl code on ISim 12.3? I know it works because I downloaded to the FPGA but I cannot see a good simulation.

Thanks in advance and sorry if it's too basic but I'm very new to this.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use work.packageFlipFlop.all;
use work.packageUtilities.all;

entity contadorFlipFlopD is
    Port ( CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;
           E : in  STD_LOGIC;
              CLEAR: in STD_LOGIC;
           S : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0)
            );
end contadorFlipFlopD;

architecture Behavioral of contadorFlipFlopD is
    signal dEFFD, dSFFD, aux: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := (others=>'0');
    --signal CLKslow: std_logic;
begin

    aux(0) <= E;
    aux(1) <= aux(0) AND dSFFD(0);
    aux(2) <= aux(0) AND dSFFD(0);
    aux(3) <= aux(0) AND dSFFD(0);

    dEFFD(0) <= aux(0) XOR dSFFD(0);
    dEFFD(1) <= aux(1) XOR dSFFD(1);
    dEFFD(2) <= aux(2) XOR dSFFD(2);
    dEFFD(3) <= aux(3) XOR dSFFD(3);

    --dF0: divisorFrecuencia PORT MAP(CLK, CLEAR, CLKslow);

    ffD0: flipFlopD PORT MAP( dEFFD(0), CLK, dSFFD(0) );
    ffD1: flipFlopD PORT MAP( dEFFD(1), CLK, dSFFD(1) );
    ffD2: flipFlopD PORT MAP( dEFFD(2), CLK, dSFFD(2) );
    ffD3: flipFlopD PORT MAP( dEFFD(3), CLK, dSFFD(3) );

    S <= dSFFD;

end Behavioral;




library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity flipFlopD is
    Port ( D, CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Q : out  STD_LOGIC);
end flipFlopD;

architecture a_flipFlopD of flipFlopD is

begin
    process (CLK)
    begin
        if (clk'event AND clk = '1') then
            Q <= D;
        end if;
    end process;
end a_flipFlopD;
```

this is what my testbench looks like

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

ENTITY test IS
END test;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF test IS 

    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    COMPONENT contadorFlipFlopD
    PORT(
         CLK : IN  std_logic;
         E : IN  std_logic;
         CLEAR : IN  std_logic;
         S : OUT  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT;


   --Inputs
   signal CLK : std_logic := '0';
   signal E : std_logic := '1';
   signal CLEAR : std_logic := '0';

    --Outputs
   signal S : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

    --Signals
    signal dEFFD, dSFFD, aux: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000";
    signal CLKslow: std_logic := '0';


   -- Clock period definitions
   constant CLK_period : time := 20 ns;

BEGIN

    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: contadorFlipFlopD PORT MAP (
          CLK => CLK,
          E => E,
          CLEAR => CLEAR,
          S => S
        );

   -- Clock process definitions
   CLK_process :process
   begin
        CLK <= '0';
        wait for CLK_period/2;
        CLK <= '1';
        wait for CLK_period/2;
   end process;


   -- Stimulus process
   stim_proc: process
   begin        
      -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
      wait for 100 ns;  

      wait for CLK_period*10;

      -- insert stimulus here 

      wait;
   end process;

END;
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about how the simulation isn't what you expect?  Can't compile? Can't see waveforms?  Waveforms aren't what you expect?  What does your testbench code look like?

Comment: Yes. When I open ISim without making a testbench (I don't understand testbenchs) I force clock and force constant on CLK, and Reset respectively but in my output S always I get "UUUU".

Answer (score 2):

You need a testbench to stimulate your design and capture the waveforms.

[Something like this](http://esd.cs.ucr.edu/labs/tutorial/tb_mux.vhd)

Comment: I've follow your testbench but still getting "UUUU" in output.